# VBA: elseIf condition for cell color does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use Elseif to get a green color on a specific cell if elseif-condition is true but it didn't work. As you see in the code, I want elseif condition to get a green color on cell M5 if the condition is true but it doesn't. Btw the If condition is working.

Thanks for helping.

```
 For j = 10 To LastRow
If Cells(j, "M") = "" And Cells(j, "N") = "" Then
Cells(5, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf Cells(j, "M") <> "" And Cells(j, "N") <> "" Then
Cells(5, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
 
 Next j
```

I also tried this code but it does not work

```
For j = 10 To LastRow
If Cells(j, "M") = "" And Cells(j, "N") = "" Then
Cells(5, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
Cells(5, "M").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End if
```

Comment: 1: The same cell from row 5 is used for all the rows, is it the expected behavior?

Comment: 2: Your code set the color of M5 to red or green, according to the last row where either both cells in columns M and N are empty nor both are not empty. There is no color change when one cell is blank and the other isn't.

Comment: @VincentG yes you have right but when I changde to Or from and AND it does not work either. IF you see my answer below. That code was I tried first but it didn't work so I puted on Elseif.

Comment: You code works fine, and does exactly what it is expected to do... but maybe not what YOU want it to do. Exactly what are the results you expect? Maybe you can edit your question to add some sample of the expected results

Comment: In your second code, the result depends only on the values of the Cells(LastRow, "M") and Cells(LastRow, "N"). You can remove the whole for loop and get the same results.